# How can I remove Amazon Prime Video from my Android device using the Android Debugging Bridge (ADB)?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, bloatware

I'm following [this guide](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/) to remove bloatware on my Android device. So far I was able to remove the apps that I didn't want on my phone, but whenever I try to uninstall Amazon Prime Video using ADB I keep getting thrown this error:

> Failure [not installed for 0]

The command that caused this error to appear was:

> pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.amazon.avod.thirdpartycilent

Why am I getting this error and how can I remove Amazon Prime Video from my phone? I can see that the app is installed for me (see below) but it shows up as if it isn't installed whenever I try to uninstall it using ADB.

[image: Amazon Pic]

My phone's model is an LG G8 ThinQ and it runs Android 10.

Comment: Can you provide the output of the command `adb shell pm list packages --user 0 amazon`? Also, if you deem an app as bloatware I don't think you should be keeping its data lying around, in which case omit `-k` in the uninstall command.

Comment: Do you mean in the post or in a comment?

Comment: In the question would be good